# Replacing NSURLConnection with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have been tasked with replacing all `NSURLConnection` code with `AFNetworking` code. I am not terribly familiar with either, one thing that puzzles me is how to replace this line:

```
self.urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:true];
```

I have tried this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:self.urlRequest];
```

but `AFHTTPRequestOperation` has no delegate property. Is there an equivalent in `AFNetworking` that will call a delegate for `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods?

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking tends towards a block based approach so you would use `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` to supply blocks to deal with the successfully received data or the failure error.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking won't use your old `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods. It replaces a lot of that detailed delegate-based code with something far simpler, a block-based interface. You'll likely be ripping out a lot of the existing code that builds your `urlRequest` object as well as much of the delegate methods you have. The whole idea of AFNetworking is to get you out of the gory details of that sort of code.

Having said that, you really shouldn't try to replace `NSURLConnection` code with AFNetworking without a little more familiarity on AFNetworking, at the very least. I'd suggest going through the AFNetworking examples found on their [README](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) page, perhaps going through a few AFNetworking tutorials, too (just google it and you should find many).

I would suggest going through your existing `NSURLConnection` code, making sure you understand what it's trying to do at a high level (e.g. `GET` vs `POST`, JSON vs x-www-form-urlencoded requests, etc.), and then take a crack at replacing it with AFNetworking. We're happy to help if you do a little research and try it yourself. And, it's quite possible that you probably won't even need our help once you see how easy AFNetworking really is. But you need to do a little research and give it a go first.